# I am trying to a get a data table widget where the skills and uri link is supposed to come from a json file. I have data.dart to read from json

Tags: flutter

Data.dart file is as follows where I getting the error of **"The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'."**

```
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_new, deprecated_member_use, prefer_collection_literals

class Data {
  late String previous;
  late String next;
  late List<Results> results;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    previous = json['previous'];
    next = json['next'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>(results);
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Results {
  String skills = " ";
  String test = "";

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    skills = json['skills'];
    test = json['test'];
  }
}
```

I have a dataprovider file as well which is as follows:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:table_widget_project1/data.dart';

class MyDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Data d;

  Future getData(context) async {
    // You can call an API to get data, once we've the data from API or any other flow... Following part would always be the same.
    // We forgot about one more important part .. lets do that first

    // We need access to BuildContext for loading this string and it's not recommended to store this context in any variable here
    // in change notifier..
    var response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('./lib/data.json');
    // now we have response as String from local json or and API request...
    var mJson = json.decode(response);
    // now we have a json...
    d = Data.fromJson(mJson);
    notifyListeners(); // for callback to view
  }
}
```

Sample Json data is this

```
{
    "skills": [{
            "skills": "C#",
            "test": "//www.google.com/"
        },
        {
            "skills": ".Net Core",
            "test": "//www.google.com/"
        },
        {
            "skills": "ASP.Net",
            "test": "//www.google.com/"
        }
}

Everything from JSON should be printed in a data table widget with columns skills, months, selfscore, testscore, testlink and comments 
only the skill and test link is coming from JSON file. Month, selfscore and comments are ditable fields
```

Comment: Show the exact error please (with stack).

Comment: can you share your response data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.html - `List` constructor takes an optional `int` parameter, not `List`, also note that it is deprecated in null-safe code

Comment: I have updated the entire question. Also, I am on a beginner level so knowledge is limited.

Comment: `results = new List<Results>(results);` - here you cannot use `results` as a parameter - you could pass some `int` value but again: in null-safe code you should do what they say here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.html - if you are on beginner level (and not only) read official documentation first

Comment: I am actually left it empty now ```results = new List<Results>();``` but it is still giving an error. I will read the documentation

Comment: you can also read [Iterable collections](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables) - perfect material for beginners